# How can I find repeating pairs of characters with a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to use regex to replace any occurrences of any set of two characters which repeat in a string. I would like for such patterns to be replaced with one occurrence of the repeating substring and the number of times it was repeated.

For example, in this string below, I would like:

`qwertyabababababababababababa`

to become:

`qwertyab11a`

Similarly,

`a a a a a a a a a a`

should become:

`a 9a`

I have tried running code similar to this:

```js
console.log("hello, this test did not work".replace(/([\D\D]+)/g, (...r) => {
  console.log(r);
  return r[1].slice(0, 2) + r[1].length / 2;
}));
```

but the above obviously didn't work, and returned this:

`he14.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a so-called back-reference (`\1`) to match a repetition of a captured group:

```js
console.log("did nana mouskouri sing mama mia".replace(/(\D\D)\1+/g, (all, grp) => {
    return grp + all.length / 2;
}));
```